# Reading and editing JSON files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so basically I have a bot where if you write to it !accounts, it will give you an information based on what ID you are writing to it from. If you have the ID of 662 and writing to it !account, it will check the json files for an steamID of 662. If it has it, it will display your currency and your ID.

All of that I have figured out. What I need help with is if your ID dosen't exist in my json. If it dosen't I want it to be created as a new one.

This is my json code:

```
{
    "tradesettings": {
    "pollInterval": 5000,
    "confirmationChecker": 10000,
    "acceptEscrow": false,
    "acceptScammers": false,
    "ourmaxitems": 50,
    "theirmaxitems": 5
},

"accsettings": {
    "amountofaccounts": 3
},

"accounts":[
    { "botID":"3", "steamID":"662", "balance": 0 },
    { "botID":"2", "steamID":"211", "balance": 0 },
    { "botID":"1", "steamID":"76561198026027024x", "balance": 666 },

    { "botID":"0", "steamID":"", "balance": 0 }
]}
```

And when I want to, I want to be able to add ex to the entire thing

```
        { "botID":"4", "steamID":"421", "balance": 0 },
```

So it says:

```
    "accounts":[

{ "botID":"4", "steamID":"421", "balance": 0 },
{ "botID":"3", "steamID":"662", "balance": 0 },
{ "botID":"2", "steamID":"211", "balance": 0 },
{ "botID":"1", "steamID":"951", "balance": 666 },

{ "botID":"0", "steamID":"", "balance": 0 }]
```

so that a new account has been created with a new ID. How do I do that??
Oh and btw, my bot is on myBot.js, while this json file is called config.json, same folder.

This is the code that is supposed to edit it.

```
        if(ok == 1) {
        console.log("[SERVER] "+steamID.getSteamID64()+" is asking for his account information.");
        for(r=0;r<= config.accsettings.amountofaccounts ;r++) {
            if (config.accounts[r].steamID != "undefined") {
                if(config.accounts[r].steamID == steamID.getSteamID64()) {
                    console.log("[SERVER] "+ steamID.getSteamID64() +" is asking for his account info, respondig with it.\n")
                    client.chatMessage(steamID.getSteamID64(), "\nDisplaying your account on this bot\nBotID: "+config.accounts[r].botID+"\nSteamID: "+config.accounts[r].steamID+"\nBalance: "+config.accounts[r].balance);

                    break;
                    ok = 0;
                    r = 0;

                }
            }
            if(r == config.accsettings.amountofaccounts) {

                console.log("[SERVER] "+steamID.getSteamID64()+" dosen't have an account here, creating one for him.");
                client.chatMessage(steamID.getSteamID64(),"Hold on, creating an account.\n\nDone, please type '!account' to view it\n(took 0.03 seconds)");

                //var item2={ "botID":config.accsettings.amountofaccounts+1, "steamID":steamID.getSteamID64(), "balance": 0 };
                //config.accounts.push(item2)

                config.accounts.push({botId: "10", steamID: "11", balance: 0});

                break;
                r = 0;
                ok = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```

Then there is another file which is the json file, called config.json

Comment: So your question really isn't about how to change a JSON-like object, it's really about how to read and write javascript to a file. There are many ways to do this. You need to be more specific about what environment you are running in and what you have currently to read the file.

Comment: Is there a way I can write to you in private, I've got quite some code to show you..

Comment: No, it's best to keep it all in public. If your code is proprietary, then you should be able to provide a simplified version of it that expresses your problem but does not have any private information.

Comment: Alright, I have jsut edited my question to reveal some code of mine.

Comment: How do you read in your json file? Are you using node or a browser? Also, please update your question. Your question is not about arrays and adding values, it's about reading and writing a json file.

Comment: I run it all with CMD using node mybot.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var account=[];

var item={ "botID":"3", "steamID":"662", "balance": 0 };
var item2={ "botID":"2", "steamID":"211", "balance": 0 };

account.push(item);
account.push(item2);
```

Result is :

```
[{ "botID":"3", "steamID":"662", "balance": 0 },
{ "botID":"2", "steamID":"211", "balance": 0 }]
```

if you want to use JSON as MAP then

```
var map = {};
// add a item
map[key1] = value1;
// or remove it
delete map[key1];
// or determine whether a key exists
key1 in map;
```

If you want to create new item in JSON (Array) which does not exist in JSON by ID field... First of all you have to iterate into existing JSON and act depending on response of function.

to Find item by required field (in our example by ID) you can write this function.

```
function findBySpecField(data, requestedField, value, responseField) {
    var container = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
        if (container[i][requestedField] == value) {
            return(container[i][responseField]);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm just wondering. You do know that I want it to actually edit my config.json file forever, not just until I close the bot. This isn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

In node, you should be using the [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html) to interact with the file system.  In your case, it would go something like this:

```
const filename = `${__dirname}/config.json`;
const fs = require('fs');

let config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, {encoding: 'utf8'}));

// do your stuff

fs.writeSync(filename, JSON.stringify(config), {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

Some things you need to be careful of:

1. Your file needs to be correctly formatted or your program will crash
2. If your app writes bad data, your config file is toast, you should be making backups of it.
3. Always read and write with explicit encodings specified.

Comment: For some reason I get this error:
  return binding.writeString(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                 ^

Note; I have connected to the config.json, I've already gotten some information from there, like asking for ID's is functional, just transferring them is the problem.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. What is the full text of the message? And what do you mean "connected to the json file"? Do you mean that you can read it in? And what do you mean by transferring? Do you mean writing it to disk?

Comment: I can already write something like config.accounts[0].steamID, and it will give me the steamID of the first one. I can already do that. What I need is for me to be able to create a config.accounts[1].steamID if you know what I mean.

Comment: It would be much easier if we could discuss this over email. or some other place where I can just send you the entire code.

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean. You are not being clear. Above, you say that you know how to make changes to the object, you just need to know how to write it to disk. But here, you are saying something different. Other answers to this question have described how you can use `push` to add an element to an array.

Comment: First of all, sorry if I've written something stupid. What I currently, with the current code, I can get some stuff from config.json via myBot.js

all I have to do is write: config.accounts[0].steamID, and I will get "420" for an example. I can write that in the myBot.js file and I will get it in console if I write console.log(config.accounts[0].steamID)

Comment: What I need help with is adding a entire new: { "botID":"2", "steamID":"211", "balance": 0 }, to the .json file.

Comment: So, it sounds like you have two problems: 1. being able to change your config object and 2. being able to write your config object to disk. The other answers describe how to add to the config object and my answer describes how to write to disk.

Comment: config.accounts.push(...) dosen't give me an error, but it just dosen't change anything in the actual .json file.

Comment: Yes. After you do the push, you need to WRITE the change back to a file. See my answer above.

Comment: How exactly would I put it in my code? I've tried different combinations..